# Example of affine varieties with a restriction on the dimension of an irreducible component of their intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

On Hartshorne's book of algebraic geometry, exercise 2.11 (c) page 13 it's ask to prove that for any two linear varieties $Y,Z$ in $P^n$, with $dim Y=r$, $dim Z=s$, if $r+s-n\geq 0$, then $Y\cap Z\neq \emptyset$, then $Y\cap Z$ is a linear variety of dimention $\geq r+s-n$.

I'm wondering if it can be taken to the affine variety: is there an example of $Y,Z\subset A^n$ affine varieties such that an irreducible component of $Y\cap Z$ has dimention $\geq r+s-n$?

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Have you seen Prop I.7.1?

Comment: So it works for every variety..? right?

Comment: I believe that's what it's saying. I think you could generalize (not a serious thing) to equidimensional algebraic sets. He basically could have proved this in I.3 but chose to save it for later. The main idea is using the diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

If we take your question exactly as it's written, then taking $X=Y$ of dimension $r$, we get an example as long as $\frac{n}{2} \leq r \leq n$ since we then only require $r \leq n$. However, I don't think you mean to ask whether there are examples where this inequality holds in $\mathbb{A}^n$; I think you mean to ask whether it must always hold in the affine setting.

One main difference between $\mathbb{A}^n$ and $\mathbb{P}^n$ is that any two (linear) hyperplanes in $\mathbb{P}^n$ intersect, whereas in $\mathbb{A}^n$ we can have `parallel' linear hyperplanes which do not intersect.

For instance, taking $Y=\{x=0\}$ and $Z=\{x=1\}$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$, we have $\dim Y = \dim Z = 1$, but $Y\cap Z = \emptyset$. Similar results hold for $\{z=0\}, \{z=1\}$ in $\mathbb{A}^3$.